# C++ Redistributable package with WIX

Tags: .net, visual-c++, wix

So, I wrote a code which uses some Microsoft Sql server dlls, these dlls depends on some C++ libraries. Initially the code was not working on the client's machine but when I installed C++ Redistributable Package it worked fine.

My question is how can I install these dependencies along with my code. I am using WIX to install the software.

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

First get the merge modules of C++ redistributables (MSM files). Usually they are inside the Merge Modules folder (`c:\ProgramFiles\Common Files\Merge Modules`) (for win x64 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules). Their name is based on architecture (32/64 bit) and VC++ version.

In the `<DirectoryRef>` tag for your target directory add a `<Merge>` node with these attributes:

```
<DirectoryRef>
    <Merge
        Id="MSVCRedist" DiskId="1" Language="0"
        SourceFile="Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86.msm"/>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Add the `<Feature>`:

```
<Feature
    Id="VCRedist" AllowAdvertise="no" Display="hidden" Level="1"
    Title="Visual C++ 9.0 Runtime"/>
```

Add the reference `<MergeRef>` to the previous added `<Merge>` section inside the `<Feature>` definition:

```
<MergeRef Id="MSVCRedist"/>
```

The example has been extracted [from here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_vcredist.htm).

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. It still gives error VC80.CRT not installed. can I just add the complete Redistributable package with my installer?

Comment: You can use the [WiX bootstrapper Burn](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/Lets-talk-about-Burn) to run the executable redist. Moreover I suggest to check where redist has been installed and where SQL Server DLLs are after installation.