# How do I make my visual c++ 2013 application not need redistributable package downloaded?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I've heard that statically linking the runtime libraries is usually not recommended so that's out of the question for me. But since I use vc++ 2013, I don't use the dlls that are guaranteed to be on every windows machine. So what do I do so that I don't have to say "oh, and also go to this site and download this other thing" to users, meaning, is there a way to just put those dlls in with my application? if I can, where can I get them from?

Also, I've noticed that every pc I've tested this on, I had to have the Redistributable Packages downloaded, but how is it that no other apps on peoples' computers have required them to download this if you need those for vc++ 2013?

Comment: Create an installer and package the redistributable along with your application.

Comment: @Praetorian can you go into a bit of detail on that or where I can learn more about it? I don't have much experience shipping my product

Comment: I don't have much experience with this either, so I can't be of much help, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11262435/241631) shows how to do what you want if you're using [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) to create the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple answer for you --

Choose Properties | C/C++ | Code Generation | Runtime Library

Once there, for Debug versions choose "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)"

and for Release versions choose "Multi-threaded (/MT)"

If for some strange reason that doesn't work, you must include the file "vcredist.exe" with your application.

**Taken from [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/44474/).**